# Using LSTM "Error when checking input: expected lstm_22_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (15, 33297)"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

While training the model it is showing error

> Error when checking input: expected lstm_22_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (15, 33297)

I have tried and changed the input_shape 100 of times but at last it is showing this error.

I have changed the input_dims many times using expand_dims I have also converted it but then also it is showing the same error.

```
from keras.layers import Embedding
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[0], 
X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True ))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print("Train...")
model.fit(X_test,y_test,batch_size=5, epochs=10)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-afa0c9eaa4e6> in <module>()
      1 print("Train...")
----> 2 model.fit(X_test,y_test,batch_size=5, epochs=10)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    951             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
    953         # Prepare validation data.
    954         do_validation = False

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    749             feed_input_shapes,
    750             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 751             exception_prefix='input')
    752 
    753         if y is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    126                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    127                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 128                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    129                 if not check_batch_axis:
    130                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_22_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (15, 33297)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on this line

```
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[0], 
X_train.shape[1],)))
```

you specify a 3D input, due to the comma after

```
X_train.shape[1],
```

Either remove the comma to get a 2D input or change it to

```
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape)))
```

in order to make sure that the input dimensions match.

Comment: `from keras.layers import Embedding
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True ))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])`

Comment: `print("Train...")
model.fit_generator(X_train,y_train,epochs=10,verbose=1)`

Comment: ```Train...
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-71a73a3044f8> in <module>()
      1 print("Train...")
----> 2 model.fit_generator(X_train,y_train,epochs=10,verbose=1)
```

Comment: ```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```